# Geofire is returning duplicate object keys from Firebase?

Tags: swift, geofire

I have the following lines of code which executes a Geofire query with a location and radius as parameter.

I only have 4 objects (Venues with key 'bar1...bar4') in Firebase with the required Geofire information structure (geohash and lat/lon values).

```
        let query = self.GEOFIRE_VENUES.query(at: location, withRadius: 1000)

        query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

         print ("FOUND KEY: ", key)
```

I am printing the returned '**key**' from from the query above into the console and for some reason it is returning the same key twice.

any ideas?

```
FOUND KEY:  bar2
FOUND KEY:  bar2
FOUND KEY:  bar4
FOUND KEY:  bar4
FOUND KEY:  bar3
FOUND KEY:  bar3
FOUND KEY:  bar1
FOUND KEY:  bar1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop as below;

```
let query = self.GEOFIRE_VENUES.query(at: location, withRadius: 1000)

query.observe(.keyEntered) { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

    for k in key {
        print(k)
}
```